# Window.open ignoring height and width when noopener is included in the option

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

I've been trying to specify the width and height of a popup window via `window.open` function. However, as soon as I include `noopener` in the option the width and height are ignored on Chrome.

Here's the code I'm using, https://jsfiddle.net/v0otu1kq/ in this case the window opens with specified dimensions.

However, once I include `noopener` in the option e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/1eqtLsnr/ it ignores the dimension set.

```
document.querySelector('[data-frame]').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.open(
    'https://facebook.com',
    'facebook-window',
    'width=600,height=400,scrollbar=yes,noopener' // <-- this
  );
});
```

Comment: is there a reason you can't just open this as a new tab, instead? (E.g. either a real link, or a JS-created `a` that you give target="_blank", add to the document, click, and then remove from the document again) That way you get all the security models of "opening something in a new tab" that browsers come with these days for free, and as a bonus, that navigation action ends up on the browse history.

Comment: Good question @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I actually suggested to open in new tab but client insists to use to open as popup. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: It respected width and height for me in Firefox. That's not what `noopener` does, it just makes it so you can't access the window that's opened in your code itself, so you can't control the window.

Comment: This bug was reported on Chromium bug tracker in October 2019 https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1011688 It is still available as of October 2020.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a deeper look into the documentation of the **window.open** function, and i finally found a workaround:

```
let fbWindow = window.open(
    '',
    'facebook-window',
    'width=600,height=400,scrollbar=yes'
);

fbWindow.opener = null;
fbWindow.location = 'https://facebook.com';
```

This works as follow:

1. We create a popup window with desired properties and blank URL
2. Programatically, we change the property **opener** of the created popup window to null
3. After everything is done, we change the location of the window to the desired one (if we did this before, we would come across a cross-origin error)

PS: Notice that this won't work on JSFiddle, since it is sandboxed.

Comment: Thanks, well done! This is the most correct answer as of today and compatible with older browsers.

Comment: Note, however, that in Chrome this has a lesser "isolation" effect on the opened window. New window runs in the same process. You also retain pointer to the `fbWindow`, which is implementation specific according to specs, but Chrome does not currently return window pointer when `noopener` flag is set. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#the-rules-for-choosing-a-browsing-context-given-a-browsing-context-name

Comment: this is a misleading solution. noopener is very different from window.opener = null. If you can live with window.opener = null, I think for most of the time you can live with not touching it at all. noopener in itself implies isolation i.e. the "opener" holds no reference to the popup window and vice versa. Therefore you cannot mutate the other window's state (e.g. dom) from either side. This gives browser much better freedom to optimize, e.g. running popup in different process, hence having way better rendering performance scaling up.